# Swift 4 FirebaseAuth

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-authentication

I just started Coding a new Xcode project and I used FirebaseAuth For signIn/SignOut, the problem is that when I try to sign in the user normally you would use this

```
Auth.auth().signIn(withEmail: email, password: password) { (user, error) in  // ...}
```

but when i type Auth.auth() it does not recognize the auth().
i do not know why its doing this i have used FirebaseAuth before and did not have this issue,

I have tried Quitting Xcode and reopining it, creating a new project but still dose the same thing.

if you know how to fix this please let me know thanks.

Comment: Check your pod file, make sure you can "import FirebaseAuth" here

Comment: yes I did and yes you can import FirebaseAuth

Comment: Have you added `import Firebase` or `import FirebaseAuth` to the top of your page?  Have you tried a clean and rebuild?

Comment: Yes I did import FirebaseAuth, I will try to clean and rebuild and see if that help

Answer (score 0):

Have you been to the Firebase Dashboard and added the Email/Pass Authentication Method to your Project ?